# Who is the mysterious Arms Dealer?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

During the Arms Deal and Bravo update in *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, new guns were added to the game. The idea, according to Valve, is that the update "*lets you experience all the illicit thrills of black market weapons trafficking without any of the hanging around in darkened warehouses getting knifed to death.*" Valve has made artwork for both of these updates, and there is a strange man in both of them.

In Valve's artwork for the Arms Deal update, [the man is visible sitting on a case of weapons.](http://s.pro-gmedia.com/videogamer/media/images/pub/large/arms_deal_cs_go.jpg)
In Valve's artwork for the Bravo update, [the man is visible standing up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL0DE.png)

Who is this mysterious figure? Is he the leader of the Counter-Terrorists in CSGO? Or more likely, he supplies weapons to the Terrorists in CSGO? Some people say that [he is the Gman from Half-Life.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9uOJ.png) Or is he simply part of the artwork? I am curious to know the answer.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? ;_;

Comment: Basically, how is this actually a problem you face in-game?

Comment: @Retrosaur Is there harm in being curious?

Answer (score 3):

It is simply a little bit of backstory to accompany the skin changes, nothing more than that.

If you wish to read more, look in to the text in the mission journals, for a man named Booth, there is quite a bit of talk about him in there.

Answer (score -2):

Well,maybe he is a black market weapon dealer for both CT and T,it is also possible that he is just a "simply part of the artwork".